# Many select queries in one session

Tags: java, performance, hibernate, jpa, transactions

I have a misunderstanding about using `@Transactional` annotation and its influence on performance.

I have a method with several select queries for collecting data via JPA repository

```
void someMethod() {
   repositoryOne.findSomething();
   repositoryTwo.findSomething();
   repositoryThree.findSomething();
   ...
}
```

I know if I put `@Transactional` annotation above a method then all queries will be executed in the single transaction and in the single session.

So, does it make sense to put `@Transactional` annotation above that method to better performance, because all queries will be executed in the single session and application will not spend time and resources on acquiring and release several connections to database?

Comment: As mentioned in the very well written answer - it depends. Don't discount though that read queries can obtain and release connections to a read-pool for reuse, while transactional methods must hold that connection for the life of the method/transaction, preventing other threads from reusing that resource. Some read connections can be used under the covers concurrently as well, so you can use far fewer DB connections for reads outside of transactions than you can within them. There are many many resources and issues to consider when deciding what to do for performance

Comment: @Chris It would be interesting to see your own answer. Is a read-pool related to the database or an application connection pool?

Comment: This is hibernate specific/tagged, and I am not familiar enough with all the settings and configuration options that I could try to answer a complex question reasonably without risking steering people wrong. Performance tuning is an art and all I can do is scribble. I mentioned a separate read pool, as this is native EclipseLink separation ( https://eclipse.dev/eclipselink/documentation/2.7/concepts/data_access006.htm  ) where it was known far fewer connection were needed for exclusive read operations than are needed for writes because of transactions.

Comment: The Transactional annotation will have no significant effect on performance. With Transactional you can ensure that your business functions leave behind consistent data. Either all data operations succeeded. Or non of them succeeded in case of error. (transaction rollback).